# Using openvpn with putty

Tags: openvpn

I have installed openvpn through dietpi using the default settings. I can connect to the server using the windows client without issue. However, I cannot connect to anything. I would like to use putty to connect to the dietpi server once in a while for maintenance.

One thing I noticed is, the server network is 192.168.xx.xx, but the ip I get is 10.x.x.x. Is this a sign that it is not configured correctly? Do I need to setup a route redirect or route gateway?

Comment: This is more a Putty usage than an Information Security question.  Perhaps SuperUser would be a more appropriate forum?

Comment: What server? Can't connect to what?

Comment: I cannot connect to anything.  The vpn server is also a samba server.  But I cannot connect to the shares.  I cannot ping the vpn server.